# Couldn't read data from json config file using curl

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to setup a new connector to read file using using REST API. Instead of passing file configuration in the command line, I am trying to pass it through file. But, while reading this file, I am getting an error. This file is placed in /usr/share directory.

**Command :**

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8083/connectors" -H "Content-type:application/json" --data @/usr/share/fileConfigSource.json

Warning: Couldn't read data from file "/usr/share/fileConfigSource.json", this
Warning: makes an empty POST.
{"error_code":500,"message":null}
```

**fileConfigSource.json :**

```
{
    "name": "file_source",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "file": "/usr/share/details.txt",
        "topics": "KTest",
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the cause:

> Couldn't read data from file

Reasons could include:

1. The file doesn't exist. For example:

   ```
   ➜ cat /this/doesnot/exist
   cat: /this/doesnot/exist: No such file or directory

   ➜ curl -X POST "http://localhost:8083/connectors" -H "Content-type:application/json" --data @/this/doesnot/exist

   Warning: Couldn't read data from file "/this/doesnot/exist", this makes an
   Warning: empty POST.
   {"error_code":500,"message":null}%
   ```
2. The file *does* exist but the user that is executing the `curl` command does not have permission to access it

   ```
   ➜ ls -l /tmp/foo.json
   --w-r--r--  1 rmoff  wheel  390  2 Jun 17:50 /tmp/foo.json

   ➜ cat /tmp/foo.json
   cat: /tmp/foo.json: Permission denied

   ➜ curl -X POST "http://localhost:8083/connectors" -H "Content-type:application/json" --data @/tmp/foo.json

   Warning: Couldn't read data from file "/tmp/foo.json", this makes an empty
   Warning: POST.
   {"error_code":500,"message":null}%
   ```

---

If you have the file in the correct place and accessible you'll get this kind of response:

```
➜ curl -X POST "http://localhost:8083/connectors" -H "Content-type:application/json" --data @/tmp/foo.json

{"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nMissing required configuration \"topic\" which has no default value.\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}%
```

To fix that error change

```
"topics": "KTest",
```

for

```
"topic": "KTest",
```

This then succeeds:

```
➜ curl -X POST "http://localhost:8083/connectors" -H "Content-type:application/json" --data @/tmp/foo.json

{"name":"file_source","config":{"connector.class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector","tasks.max":"1","file":"/usr/share/details.txt","topic":"KTest","key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter","value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter","name":"file_source"},"tasks":[],"type":"source"}%
```